# Importing Android WifiManager to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and I am trying to find out why:

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
```

is not recognized. What do I need to import in Eclipse?
The following is what I have written so far:

```
package com.my.android.wifi;

import org.python.core.PyInteger;
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

import com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

public class MonkeyWifi implements Predicate<PythonInterpreter> {

    public boolean CheckWifi (MonkeyDevice device){
        device.isWifiEnabled();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean apply(PythonInterpreter arg0)    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `android.net.wifi.WifiManager`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
I have changed to:
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager
But it still shows it as not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got resolved after adding an additional library in the Eclipse project:

```
---> ADD External JARs
```

pick:

```
sdk/platforms/android-xx/android.jar
```

now all Android API's are recognized.